# Searching for common values in R, and printing a specific result

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to find a way to group the values in V1, and then search for common value in the remaining columns, and print the "leftmost" common value in a new column.

In my input I have two common values for the first V1 group ("Red"), Vienna and Oslo and I'm trying to find logic that uses Vienna as the value that appears first in the group as you move right across the columns.

Can anyone suggest a way of doing this? I'm getting lost in a series of loops that inevitably don't provide the answer I'm looking for.

```
input = structure(list(V1 = c("Red", "Red", "Red", "Red", "Green", 
"Green"), V2 = c("Vienna", "London", "Budapest", "Vienna", "Oslo ", 
"Kyiv"), V3 = c("Lisbon", "Milan", "Vienna", "Oslo", "Rome", 
"Madrid"), V4 = c("Rome", "Barcelona", "Prague", "", "", "Dublin"
), V5 = c("Oslo", "Vienna", "Oslo", "", "", ""), V6 = c("", "Oslo", 
"", "", "", "")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

output = structure(list(V1 = c("Red", "Red", "Red", "Red", "Green", 
"Green"), V2 = c("Vienna", "London", "Budapest", "Vienna", "Oslo ", 
"Kyiv"), V3 = c("Lisbon", "Milan", "Vienna", "Oslo", "Rome", 
"Madrid"), V4 = c("Rome", "Barcelona", "Prague", "", "", "Dublin"
), V5 = c("Oslo", "Vienna", "Oslo", "", "", ""), V6 = c("", "Oslo", 
"", "", "", ""), V7 = c("Vienna", "Vienna", "Vienna", "Vienna", 
"No match", "No match")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach where I `melt()` the dataframe into long format, and count by `V1`, and selecting the first ("leftmost") value.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(input)


input[melt(input, id="V1")[, ct:=.N, .(V1, value)][ct>1, .SD[1, .(V7=value)], V1], on="V1"]
```

Output:

```
      V1       V2     V3        V4     V5   V6     V7
1:   Red   Vienna Lisbon      Rome   Oslo      Vienna
2:   Red   London  Milan Barcelona Vienna Oslo Vienna
3:   Red Budapest Vienna    Prague   Oslo      Vienna
4:   Red   Vienna   Oslo                       Vienna
5: Green    Oslo    Rome                             
6: Green     Kyiv Madrid    Dublin
```